# Can't remove image from s3 but can upload . Any fix?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In nodejs I am facing one issue is like I can upload to s3 bucket via aws-sdk nodejs. But cannot delete it. It was working fine 5 min ago. Bu t when I am trying to remove item from bucket its showing this error:

```
err AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (/Users/apple/Desktop/BeZen/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:711:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/apple/Desktop/BeZen/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/apple/Desktop/BeZen/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/apple/Desktop/BeZen/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/apple/Desktop/BeZen/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/apple/Desktop/BeZen/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/apple/Desktop/BeZen/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Desktop/BeZen/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Desktop/BeZen/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/apple/Desktop/BeZen/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  region: null,
  time: 2022-07-10T15:45:42.529Z,
  requestId: '8HV10ZFF9HC4HSWP',
  extendedRequestId: 'U7fJ3pIaXTlz/G7XsHRcd9RsHWWrBDRK1ryMYmHOriHQFfWmv9sVCgG3ZF1F/RYkyeNOlXWfKUM=',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 54.06019538095763
}
```

I have full access to the user.

[image]

Can any one tell me what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the role that the user assumes is missing s3:DeleteObject permissions.

Edit:
My bad, did not notice the user which indeed has the access. Have you checked the bucket policy?

Comment: I doubt that. His user (EducityDev) has the AmazonS3FullAccess policy attached - which allows full access to S3 and includes the DeleteObject action.

Comment: My bad, did not notice the user. Could be an issue with bucket policy.

Comment: I am so confused about that aws error. It was working fine the whole day suddenly delete showing access denied